# Is it possible to do a cross account and same account deployment in the same pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I am doing a cross account deployment in AWS from my deploy account to staging account, I have 2 seperate pipelines for API and Front end application.

In the code pipeline of API, i am creating some resources which i want to re-use in the build stage of the front end's codepipeline. Now i need to achieve the below steps by running a single pipeline

1. Deploy API cloud formation stacks from deploy account to staging account - Succesfully did it.
2. Deploy One cloud formation stack in deploy account itself - Not succesful, Is it possible? If it is possible how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CodePipeline is comprised of Stages (logical) and Actions (Source/Build/Deploy etc).

Every action can be run in local account or a cross account. How does this magic happens?

Every action has a roleArn property. This is the role that CodePipeline "assumes" when performing that action. If that role specified in 'roleArn' property is in local account (or property is null) the action runs in local account. If the role specified in 'roleArn' property is cross account the action will run in the other account.

Run the following command to inspect:

```
$ aws codepipeline get-pipeline --name <name> --region us-east-1
```

Result will be something like (See second last line):

```
            "name": "Deploy",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "name": "Deploy",
                    "actionTypeId": {
                        "category": "Deploy",
                        "owner": "AWS",
                        "provider": "CloudFormation",
                        "version": "1"
                    },
                    "runOrder": 1,
                    "configuration": {
                        "ActionMode": "CREATE_UPDATE",
                        "Capabilities": "CAPABILITY_IAM,CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM,CAPABILITY_AUTO_EXPAND",
                        "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/CrossAccount_Role",
                        "StackName": "Cx-Account",
                        "TemplatePath": "SourceArtifact::template.json"
                    },
                    "outputArtifacts": [],
                    "inputArtifacts": [
                        {
                            "name": "SourceArtifact"
                        }
                    ],
                    "roleArn": "arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/CrossAccount_Role",
                    "region": "us-east-1"
                }
```

> > Deploy One cloud formation stack in deploy account itself - Not succesful, Is it possible? If it is possible how to do it?

Now you have the key to running the action in whichever account you want. Create the action as normal and do not specify a roleArn on the action itself and CodePipeline will execute the cloudformation operation in the deploy account itself (where the pipeline is).

Answer (score 1):

I have had a few use cases where I need to preform actions in AWS code build from my management account (the account where I run my pipeline) to the target account I am deploying to. This is helpful when needing to deploy an angler app to S3 for example. here is my solution hope this helps :)

```
BuildAngulerProjectAndUploadToS3:
Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
Properties:
  Name: !Sub '${UniqueId}-build-anguler-project-upload-to-s3'
  Artifacts:
    Type: CODEPIPELINE
  Environment:
    ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL
    Image: aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-x86_64-standard:3.0
    Type: LINUX_CONTAINER
  ServiceRole: !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${SSMNamespace}/${PipelineSSMConfigId}/pipeline/pipeline_role_arn/mgmt:1}}'
  EncryptionKey: !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${SSMNamespace}/${PipelineSSMConfigId}/pipeline/artefact_encryption_key/arn:1}}'
  Source:
    Type: CODEPIPELINE
    BuildSpec:  !Sub |2 # Only use ${...} for substituted variables, not environment variables, to avoid issues with !Sub
      version: 0.2
      env:
        parameter-store:
          artifactory_username: "/${SSMNamespace}/${PipelineSSMConfigId}/pipeline/python-pip/username"
          artifactory_password: "/${SSMNamespace}/${PipelineSSMConfigId}/pipeline/python-pip/api"
      phases:
        pre_build:
            commands:
              # Assume the cross account role in the Target Account
              # CrossAccountDeploymentRoleArn is passed in as an environment variable
              - output=$(aws sts assume-role
                --role-arn $CrossAccountDeploymentRoleArn
                --role-session-name "x-account-code-build"
                --query 'Credentials.[SecretAccessKey,AccessKeyId,SessionToken]'
                --output text)
              - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(echo $output | cut -f2 -d ' ')
              - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo $output | cut -f1 -d ' ')
              - export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(echo $output | cut -f3 -d ' ')

        install:
          runtime-versions:
            nodejs: 10
          commands:
            - echo Installing source NPM dependencies...
            - cd $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR/client/app
            - echo Setting up artifactory...
            - printf _auth="$artifactory_password\nregistry=https://{ARTIFACTORY_ADDRESS}\nemail=$artifactory_username\nalways-auth=true" > .npmrc
            - cat .npmrc
            - npm i -g @angular/cli
        build:
          commands:
            - npm install
            - ng build --prod
            - echo uploading artifacts to S3
            - aws s3 sync dist/app s3://${UniqueId}-app-bucket-$Account_ID
```